# Powershell Variable Substitution in Octopus Deploy

Tags: powershell, octopus-deploy

I have a very simple powershell script to notify newrelic when a deployment completes on a particular component. The problem I have is that I can't get the release number to be sent correctly.

The script I am using is:

```
$NewRelicUri = "https://api.newrelic.com/deployments.xml"
$body = @{ 
    "deployment[app_name]" = "PB.Website"; 
    "deployment[revision]"= "#{Octopus.Release.Number}"; 
} 

Write-Host "Sending notification to $NewRelicUri..."
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $NewRelicUri -Headers @{ "x-api-key"="XXX" } -Method Post -Body $body -UseBasicParsing
```

This produces a deployment in newrelic with the revision `#{Octopus.Release.Number}`. I have also tried using the long hand version of `$OctopusParameters['Octopus.Release.Number']`, but this produces a deployment with a revision of ``` System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary``2[System.String,System.String]['Octopus.Release.Number'] ```

How can I get octopus to put send the actual release number to newrelic?

Comment: Don't use newrelic, so I can't really test but I'd try this:  "deployment[revision]"= "$($OctopusParameters['Octopus.Release.Number'])"

Comment: That did the job. Fancy moving your comment to an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't use NewRelic, so I can't really test it, but that error your getting in your long hand version indicates you need to use a subexpression for that value:

```
 "deployment[revision]"= "$($OctopusParameters['Octopus.Release.Number'])"
```

If the release number is already as string, you might get by with just:

```
"deployment[revision]" = $OctopusParameters['Octopus.Release.Number']
```